# How to make a Statcom or an inverter or a control in PSSE with fortan?

Tags: fortran, psse

I am an Electrical Engineer working recently with PSSE. I am asked to build a STATCOM model but i don't know where to start. I don't know where to start Fortran how to open it and starting to build a model (like its can be build with blocks in DigSilent or Matlab.) or to edit any existing model Any suggestion or tutorial will be extremely helpful.

Comment: If you look at the history of `psse` questions here on SO you will see that there is no active pool of experts waiting to answer questions such as yours.  You should direct your question to your favourite search engine and look for topics such as *psse tutorial*.

Comment: Thank you Mark. What can i do ? what steps to follow ? how to find my favourite search engine